# Redirecting issue to a random id in Laravel

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-4

In Laravel 4.2 I have a route defined like this:

```
Route::get('author/{id}/edit', ...);
```

When I tried to redirect to a link with a random id like previous one it failed:

```
return Redirect::to('author/{id}');
// or
return Redirect::to('author/(:any)');
```

But it works successfully when I use redirect to a id manually like:

```
return Redirect::to('author/8');
// or
return Redirect::to('author/9');
```

How to redirect to any random id or how to use redirect parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to use named routes, this way you can always point to the named route. When the URL changes, your application will still work based on the name of the route. In your case, you could use:

```
Route::get('author/{id}/edit', ['as' => 'author.edit', 'uses' => 'AuthorController@edit']);
```

This way the name of the route is 'author.edit'.

When you try to redirect to this route, you can use 
`Redirect::route('author.edit', $authorId);`

I tested this, and it also works with a random id, for example:

```
return Redirect::route('author.edit', rand());
```

Comment: thanks dear :-) 
return Redirect::route('author', array($id)); or 
return Redirect::route('author', $id); 
these two worked actually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to a random author page try this:

```
$random_id = array_rand(Author::lists('id'),1);
return Redirect::to("author/$random_id");
```

This assumes you have an Author class that extends Eloquent.

Comment: thanks
return Redirect::route('author', array($id)); or 
return Redirect::route('author', $id); 
these two worked actually.